# Build Error In SSIS 2008

Tags: ssis

Can anyone help me.

I have deleted a number of test packages I had in SSIS.

Now when I run one of the remaining ones I get a build error.

Error 1 Cannot create the output file "G:\SQL\Proj\bin\Budgets_Delete.dtsx": Could not find file 'G:\SQL\Proj\Budgets_Delete.dtsx'

This is an old package that I have deleted. The package I am running seems to work OK I just get this error message every time.

and this does not allow me to create Delpoyment Utility.

Please help me. EVEN I re saved the package, but no luck

Comment: Create a new project and then right click on packages in the right hand corner and then add existing package and add the package and save it and it should work.

Comment: Right click on your project and select Rebuild. If the error persists, then a package has a reference to the missing package and you will need to resolve it.